# Exception has occurred: ValueError not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python, opencv

When i run my code i get this error Exception has occurred: ValueError
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import controlledhandmouse as htm
import time
import autopy
    
wCam, hCam = 640, 480
    
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)
pTime = 0
detector = htm.handDetector(maxHands=1)
    
    
while True:

    succes, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime-pTime) 
    pTime = cTime
    cv2.putText(img,str(int(fps)), (20,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,3,(255,0,0), 3)
                

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

The code should open my camera via python marking my hand using opencv and i saw other posts similar to mine but in none of them is the answer to a opencv problem so i can't understand what they were saying

And here is the controlledhandmouse code that i written

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time


class handDetector():
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=1, modelComplexity=1, 
detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
    self.mode = mode
    self.maxHands = maxHands
    self.modelComplex = modelComplexity
    self.detectionCon = detectionCon
    self.trackCon = trackCon

    self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, 
self.modelComplex, 
                                    self.detectionCon, 
self.trackCon)
    

    
    self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
    # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

    if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            if draw:
                self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                           
self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
    return img

def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):

    lmList = []
    if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
        for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
            # print(id, lm)
            h, w, c = img.shape
            cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
            # print(id, cx, cy)
            lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
            if draw:
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 6, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

    return lmList


def main():
pTime = 0
cTime = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = handDetector()
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        print(lmList[4])

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                (255, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
  File "C:\Users\r7aul\Desktop\HandTrackingModule\cameratrack.py", line 19, in <module>
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Edit it into the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: I can't find the documentation of the `controlledhandmouse` module. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: yes i edited my question so you can see everything about that module that is written by me,sorry for not beeing clear is my first time asking here

Comment: You'll get that error if `self.results.multi_hand_landmarks` empty. Also, if `len(myHand.landmark)` is something other than 2 you'll get an error.

Comment: You should probably be looping over the result of `findPosition()`, since it returns a list of all the positions.

Comment: could you show me the code?

Comment: Something like `for id, x, y in detector.findPosition(img):` I don't know what you expect `lmlist` and `bbox` to be, since the function doesn't return anything like that.

Comment: BTW, the indentation in `controlledhandmouse` is all messed up in the question. Can you repost it with the actual indentation?

Comment: idk doesn t work

Comment: You wrote the class but you don't know how to use it?

Comment: The script never uses `lmList` or `bbox`. What's the point of that line?

Comment: i copied this from a youtuber and the lmList and bbox probably will use while moving my hand so my mouse can follow because of the box that is arund it

Comment: The `main()` function shows a proper way to use the result of `detector.findPosition(img)`.